# function to retrieve data from one column based on data from another column in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, output

I have a farmers market data set and one of the columns is "MarketName" (column2) and one is "WIC" (column21). I wrote a function to retrieve the market name if the WIC column = Y. My output should be a list of 2,207 names however I am getting an output of 8,144 rows because for the rows where the WIC column = N, my output is showing NA. There are 45 columns and 8,144 rows but here is a fake data set with only two columns

```
MarketName <- c("Union Springs Famers Market","Union Square Farmers Market", "Union Square Greenmarket", "Union Street Farmers Market", "Unity Market Day Farmers", "University Farmers Market") 
WIC <- c("Y","N","N","N","Y","Y")
data3 <- data.frame(MarketName, WIC)
data3$MarketName <- as.character(data3$MarketName)
data3$WIC <- as.character(data3$WIC)
```

This is my function (which could be the problem?)

```
marketacceptWIC <- function(mydf)
{
    market <- 0
    for(i in 1:length(data3$WIC))
    {
        if(data3[i,2] == "Y")
            market[i] <- data3[i,1]
    }
    return(market)
}
```

This is a sample of the output that I am getting

```
[1] "Union Springs Famers Market" NA                            NA                            NA                           
[5] "Unity Market Day Farmers"    "University Farmers Market"
```

What I want is just a list of the farmers markets that accept WIC

```
[1] "Union Springs Farmers' Market"                                                       
[2] "Unity Market Day Farmers"                                                         
[3] "University Farmers Market"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `for` loop here. Try to subset on WIC column. If you only need the `MarketName` column then

```
data3[data3$WIC == "Y", ]$MarketName

[1] "Union Springs Famers Market" "Unity Market Day Farmers"    "University Farmers Market"
```

Comment: Also you can't index a column name within a function with $ . Your function took a data frame and tried to select a column (WIC) by data$WIC, which won't work. Try data[,"WIC"] for that kind of thing....but yes, just use a subset operation like Ronak said.

Comment: @Chris: Are you sure that's true? It would make more sense to use `mydf$WIC`, but if `data` is defined before the function, his version should still work, I think? Definitely not recommended though!

Comment: I can't do a subset because the real data set has 45 columns and I only want to return the names of the markets that accept WIC (one column).

Comment: @S.Galleg check the updated answer. If that is what you want.

Comment: oh whoops, I didn't see the mydf3 defined before the function defintion... It's a function with no actual arguments (mydf not appearing in body).